# Need help to solve the trigonometric equation $\tan\frac {1+x}{2} \tan \frac {1+x}{3}=-1$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I solve the equation $\tan\frac {1+x}{2} \tan \frac {1+x}{3}=-1$. Please give me some hint for that. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $\tan(\frac{1+x}2)?$

Comment: Oh sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $\frac12,\frac13$ are measured in radian,

$$\tan\left(\frac{1+ x}2\right)=-\frac1{\tan\left(\frac{1+ x}3\right)}=-\cot\left(\frac{1+ x}3\right)=\tan\left(\frac\pi2+\frac{x+1}3\right)$$ as $\tan(\frac\pi2+C)=-\cot C$

So, $$\frac{1+ x}2=n\pi+\frac\pi2+\frac{x+1}3$$ where $n$ is any integer as $\tan A=\tan B\implies A=n\pi+B$.

---

Alternatively, we know $$\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$$

If $\tan A\tan B=-1,\tan(A-B)=\infty\implies A-B=m\pi+\frac\pi2$ where $m$ is any integer

or, $$\tan A\tan B=-1\implies \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}=-\frac{\cos B}{\sin B}$$
$$\implies \cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B=0\implies \cos(A-B)=0\implies A-B=(2r+1)\frac\pi2$$  where $r$ is any integer.

Comment: Indeed, I was stuck in what you stated thorugh the last paragraph.

Comment: @NedDabby, hope, I could make the idea clear. Added another method to avoid dealing with $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: According to your equation, note that $\tan\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)=-\cot\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+1+\frac{x}{3}\right)$

Comment: Should be $\frac {x}{3}$ at the end?

Comment: Opps! Thanks Calvin for that.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I made my answer before the OP edited it, so it differs from Lab's answer.

Comment: I'm aware of that from lab's clarification (which is why I edited the question). Yours is correct, given the original interpretation.

Comment: Nice answer to original question! +1